# How do i read HDMI input (say coming from another video source) in qt app meant to be run in an android device (amlogic)

Tags: qt, hardware-interface, hdmi-cec

How do i read HDMI input (say coming from another video source) in qt app meant to be run in an android device (@AMLogic chipset)

Comment: Typically you cannot - what evidence do you have that your device has HDMI capture capability?  Very few devices do; HDMI *output* capability in no way implies the reverse ability to *capture*.

Answer (score 0):

## You need an HDMI capture dongle/card

It can be something as simple as a cheap USB capture card, which works like a fake Webcam (Google about HDMI-USB Capture). Or (if your Amlogic device is in fact a dev board with PCI slots) it can be something a lot more high end, those cards start with things like the Decklink Quad and cost hundreds if not thousands of dollars depending on the brand and model.

With the USB dongles you can easily capture HDMI like any other V4L2 webcam. With the Broadcast-grade cards you will need to enter the GStreamer territories.